# Is it possible to display 10 bit color for a HDR monitor?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering is it is even possible to use 10 bit color, and in pygame in particular.

I tried to do some searches pertaining to using python to create images with 10 bit color depth for high end displays and came up with nothing.

For my current project I am using pygame as a pattern generator to create images that I am putting on a 4k HDR display and I wanted to see whether I could take advantage of the 10 bit color depth.